# Dilemma situation - need to reRender a mandatory inputField

Tags: visualforce

I try to make this piece of code minimal here:

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!populateCaseDetails}" name="populateCaseDetails" reRender="caseDetailPanel, message"
     oncomplete="disableCaseFields()"/>
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Case Details</h3>
    </div>
    <apex:outputPanel id="caseDetailPanel">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="col-form-label">Was a Reporting Restriction imposed?</label>
                <apex:inputField id="caseRestriction" styleClass="form-control" value="{!curCase.Was_a_Reporting_Restriction_imposed__c}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Note that by calling the actionFunction populateCaseDetails I need to reRender caseDetailPanel which includes the inputField.

The inputField is of picklist type, so I can't change it to apex:inputText. And there is no such thing as apex:inputSelect.

And I can't set this actionFunction to be immediate=true otherwise the setter won't work.

So how should I walk around this issue?

Comment: Why are you rerendering. Sounds like issue is only when it is blank.  Knowing the scenarios may help

Comment: @Eric our scenario is to let the user be able to pick up an existing case, or type a new one. If it is existing, it pre-populates the information. Otherwise, the user need to type in the information.

Comment: Then I would give them that choice then render the divs either filled in or blank. Basically don’t show it until you know if it is existing or manual entry